# Weird placement on tables

Tags: html, css

Okay so im coding and hosting a website for a project we do in school and im trying to create a "about us"-tag. we are 6 people and i have 6 photos, names and workdescriptions that i have placed in a table. i have the table exactly as i want but its placement is way of point.

code is as following...

```
<div class="mainContent">

    <div class="content" style="width: 80%;">

        <article class="topContent">

            <header class="omosstext">
                <h2 style="color: #D7622C">more random text</h2>
                <p>some random text</p>
            </header>

                 <table class="oss" style="border-spacing: 50px 2px;">
                  <tr style="line-height: 20px;">
                    <td><img src="img/pic1.jpg" class="image1"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/pic2.jpg" class="image1"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/pic3.jpg" class="image1"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/pic4.jpg" class="image1"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/pic5.jpg" class="image1"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/pic5.jpg" class="image1"></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr style="line-height: 20px;">
                    <td>name1</td>
                    <td>name2</td>
                    <td>name3</td>
                    <td>name4</td>
                    <td>name5</td>
                    <td>name6</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="line-height:20px;">
                    <td>VD</td>
                    <td>Webbansvarig</td>
                    <td>Grafisk Designer</td>
                    <td>Ekonom</td>
                    <td>Grafisk Designer</td>
                    <td>Kontaktperson</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
          </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want preview of complete set --> http://gguf.se/kontakt.html

Thanks! :)

Comment: What's wrong with the way it is now and what did you want it to look like?

Comment: Try the inspector/firebug to see what's going on. You've set margin: 200px to table, might want to remove/reduce that!

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.topContent table {
    display: block;
    margin: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

Your margin is set to 200px.
I think you may have meant 20px?    :)
Hope this helps!